# how to solve dynamic list type casting error in Hive?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

sorry I am new in using Flutter and using Hive local storage.

I am using

```
  hive: ^2.0.4
  hive_flutter: ^1.0.0
```

I open the box in main function like this

```
Future<void> main() async {

  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox<List<Event>>("events");

}
```

after getting the data from the server, I save all the events to hive by using code like this

```
final eventsBox = Hive.box<List<Event>>("events");
final List<Event> eventsFromServer = await getEventsFromServer();
eventsBox.put("recommended_events", eventsFromServer);
```

but I have error when trying to read the data from the box, I read it like this

```
final eventsBox = Hive.box<List<Event>>("events");

// error in this one line below
final eventsFromHive = eventsBox.get("recommended_events", defaultValue: []) ?? [];
```

> type 'List < dynamic > ' is not a subtype of type 'List< Event >?' in type
> cast

how to solve this type casting error?

from the documentation in [here](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/read_write) it is said

> Lists returned by get() are always of type List (Maps of type
> Map<dynamic, dynamic>). Use list.cast() to cast them to a
> specific type.

I don't know if it is the solution of my problem or not, but I don't know how to implement that in my code.

I tried it like this, but I still have the same error

```
final eventsFromHive = eventsBox.get("recommended_events")!.cast<Event>();
```

or maybe the way I write the syntax to save and read the list are totally wrong? please help :)

Comment: `final eventsFromHive = eventsBox.get("recommended_events", defaultValue: <Event>[]) ?? [];`

Comment: @sajithlakmal unfortunately it doesn't work :(

Comment: What is you `Event` object

Comment: Can you please post your events model class definition

Answer (score 4):

I can finally solve it by using it like this. in main function

```
Future<void> main() async {

  await Hive.initFlutter();
  await Hive.openBox("events");

}
```

when saving data list

```
final eventsBox = Hive.box("events");
eventsBox.put("recommended_events", eventsFromServer);
```

and read it like this

```
final eventsBox = Hive.box("events");
final eventsFromHive = eventsBox.get("recommended_events")?.cast<Event>() ?? [];
```

Answer (score 3):

Is not necessary to open your box as a List, because it is a box and can store many objects of the type that you declare, for example:

```
await Hive.openBox<MyModel>(boxName);
```

To get all the objects or data stored in that box, you can query like this:

```
final box = Hive.box<CompanyModel>(boxName);
List<CompanyModel> interviews = box.values.toList();
```

In addition, you have to create an **Adapter Model** if you want to store your own Model with Hive.

There is two dev dependencies to auto generate the Model:

```
dev_dependencies: 
  hive_generator: 
  build_runner:
```

Importing that dependencies and running this command ***flutter packages pub run build_runner build*** will generate the Model, but also you have to create your Model as the documentation indicates.

I suggest you to check out the documentation.

[Hive - Generate Adapter](https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/custom-objects/generate_adapter)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this kind of problem. It was absolutely the same. I do not know how you got kinda problem. Maybe it was the same with mine. I have just cleaned the box. and it has worked on me.

**Cause: **

I started it immediately after I made the box (for testing). he had taken the `List<dynamic>` object as it store. Once I made it clear, it stocked up data I had just given and it worked

**Try:**

`boxName.clear()` inside `initState()` and re-run it. if it will work do not forget to delete the line!

**if you forget, it will clear the box every time.**

Answer (score 0):

Done with getting Hive as an List Object :)

```
Future<List<CustomModel>> getModels() async {
 //box = await Hive.openBox<CustomModel>(Constants.Hive);
 return box?.values.toList(growable: false)?.cast<CustomModel>() ?? <CustomModel>[];
}
```